# Custom observable not able to be chained

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to create a custom observable operator, "write", that will chain to an observable stream and output the contents of observable stream.

The following code works:

```
RX.Observable.write = function() {
    return RX.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        try{
            observer.onNext("this is a test message");
            observer.onCompleted();
        } catch(exception){
            observer.onError(exception);
        }
    });
};

var observable = RX.Observable.write(); 
var subscription = observable.subscribe( function (x) { 
    console.log(x);
} );
```

But the following code, with added "range(0, 5)" does not work and kicks out an exception:

```
var observable = RX.Observable.range(0,5).write();  
                                          ^
TypeError: Object #<RangeObservable> has no method 'write'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ericbroda/Development/rxstream/index.js:15:43)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

There is probably a simple thing that I am missing but it escapes me right now.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, I wanted to post the final solution I worked out -- I now can write an observable to a node stream using the RX observable pattern:

```
var RX = require("rx");
var util = require('util');

RX.Observable.prototype.write = function(stream, encoding, cb) {

    var source = this;

    return new RX.AnonymousObservable(function(observer) {

        return source.subscribe (
            function(x) { 
                observer.onNext(x);
                stream.write(x, encoding, cb(data));
            },
            function(e) {
                observer.onError(e);
            },
            function() {
                observer.onCompleted();
            }, 
            source);

        return function() {
            // console.log('disposed');
        };
    });
};
```

The above "writable" observable can be used as follows below.  The example is illustrated using a node app writing the observable stream to node's stdout for illustration purpose but any stream such as a file can be used (note: you will need to address encoding in the appropriate fashion).  This makes it very simple to write observables using the regular RX observable pattern.

```
var RX = require("rx");
var util = require('util');

var observable = RX.Observable.range(0,5).write(process.stdout, 'utf8', function(x){
    console.log("stream completion callback called, x: %s", x);
});

var subscription = observable.subscribe( function (x) { 
    console.dir(x);
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are placing write on the Rx.Observable object, essentially creating a static method. If you want it to work in the middle of a chain you need to add it to the prototype 'Rx.Observable.prototype.write'.

Even then though, this will probably not behave as you want. It'll disregard the incoming `RangeObservable` and simply return "this is a test message" once then complete. So in the instance method you will need to handle the incoming Observable, i.e. `this`.

```
Rx.Observable.prototype.write = function() {
  var source = this;
  return source.map(/*Do something with incoming data*/);
};
```